# Error in vue-simple-suggest when item is selected

Tags: vue.js, vue-simple-suggest

In my vue/cli 4 / Bootstrap 4.3 app I make suggestion component(using vue-simple-suggest) 
with some additive parameters and returning data I need to get slug 
field of selected row and to redirect to other page
based on this slug.  Search works ok for me, but when Item in selection list is selected
I see in browsers console one more request to database with whole selected item object and that
raise error.
I make:

```
<vue-simple-suggest
        id="search_string"
        v-model="search_string"
        display-attribute="name"
        value-attribute="slug"
        :list="simpleSuggestionList"
        autocomplete=off
        mode="select"
        @select="taskSuggestionSelected()"
></vue-simple-suggest>
```

and js code:

```
simpleSuggestionList() {
    let filters={
        search_string : this.search_string, // search
        only_free : ( this.cbx_only_free ? 1 : 0), // additive parameters
        price_min : this.tasksPriceRange[0],
        price_max : this.tasksPriceRange[1],
        selectedCategories : this.getSelectedCategories
    }
    console.log('filters::')
    console.log(filters)
    return axios.post(this.apiUrl + '/tasks-search', filters, this.credentialsConfig)
        .then(({data}) => {
            return data.tasks
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
            this.showPopupMessage('Tasks search', error.response.data.message, 'warn')
        })

    // return this.retArray
},


taskSuggestionSelected() {
    console.log('\'taskSuggestionSelected par1 ::\'+par1 +"  search_string::"+this.search_string::')
    return false
}
```

1) Why error and how not to trigger request to server when item is selected and 
2) how can I save/ pass slug of selected item into taskSuggestionSelected method as I need to make redirection?

```
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-simple-suggest": "^1.10.1",
```

Thanks!